# Is amazon lambda suitable for web scraping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, cloud, aws-lambda

If I create a function to get webpages. Will it execute it on different IP per execution so that my scraping requests dont get blocked?

Comment: From the scraped website's perspective, what you're doing is malicious. Scraping can cause damaging and costly load to web servers, and the IP filtering you're encountering is a defense against that. If you're successful in getting around that defense, you will cause someone a lot of money and aggravation.

Comment: From the user perspective sometime scraping is necessary just because websites failed to deliverer consistent APIs or Notifications systems. Not all crawler are malicious

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lambda by default executes with random IPs. You can trigger it using things like event bridge so you can have a schedule to execute the script every hour or similar. Others can possibly recommend using API Gateway, however, it is highly insecure to expose API endpoints available for anyone to trigger. So you have to write additional logic to protect it either by hard coded headers or say oauth.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this AWS pipeline:
[image]

Where at source on the left you will have an EC2 instance with [JAUNT](http://jaunt-api.com/) which then feeds the URLS or HTML pages into a Kinesis Stream. The Lambda will do your HTML parsing and via Firehose stuff everything into S3 or Redshift.
The JAUNT can run via a standard WebProxy service with a rotating IP.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda doesn't have a fixed IP source as mentioned [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=679504)
however, I guess this will happen when it gets cooled down, not during the same invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal private IP address isn't what is seen by the web server, it's the public ip address from AWS.  As long as you are setting the headers and signaling to the webserver that your application is a bot.  See this link for some best practices on creating a web scrapper:

https://www.blog.datahut.co/post/web-scraping-best-practices-tips

Just be respectful of how much data you pull and how often is the main thing in my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

Lambda is triggered when a file is placed in S3, or data is being added to Kinesis or DynamoDB. That is often backwards of what a web scraper needs, though certainly things like S3 could perform as a queue/job runner.

Scraping on different IPs? Certainly lambda is deployed on many machines, though that doesn't actually help you, since you can't control the machines or their IP.

Comment: Not controlling the IP does help, it's exactly what you want -- a new IP every invocation of a scrape job right? Also, s3, kinesis and dynamoDb are not the only options for running lambda function. You can invoke lambda functions on demand using the sdk or cli. It's possible you could have a program reading from SNS/SQS for "scraping jobs" and then invoking lambda functions to perform the scrape.

Comment: Not controlling the IP address means you could end up with all queries coming from the same IP, or randomly coming from blocked IPs, and you have no way to remove those from your pool. @nackjicholson

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well getting around screen scraping bans is probably not something amazon is trying to solve with Lambda :)

Comment: API Gateway can trigger AWS Lambda.

Comment: You can also automatically trigger at regular intervals (scheduled events) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Moreover, for an easy lambda experience, have a look at Serverless http://serverless.com

Comment: can ip rotation effect can also be achieved with other services, like heroku?